Windows Boot Manager automatically boots first after booting for the first time in Windows after installing Ubuntu
So, first time into Ubuntu. I have been trying for the past few days to get this to work, but couldn't. That's the problem:
Successfully installed Ubuntu, all good. My PC restarted and got into the Grub Menu (I also checked BIOS and UEFI boot order settings, Ubuntu was first, HOWEVER, there was NO Windows Boot Manager in the boot order at all! I ignored that since everything was ok)
My PC booted to Ubuntu, so when I wanted to go back to Windows 10, I rebooted, and selected from the GRUB menu Windows Boot Manager.
HOWEVER, when I went back to switch to Ubuntu, there was NO GRUB menu. It was like I never installed Ubuntu. It just booted straight to Windows 10.
Checked UEFI and BIOS. The "Ubuntu" was completelyreplaced by Windows Boot Manager.
What's up with that?!?! I have been trying everything all day! Ubuntu is still installed but I just can't access it?!?! I tried with commands to download again GRUB (repair), but even if it said it completed, nothing happended.
My computer is pretty old, pre built from 2012 I think, HP 6300 Pro Micro tower, Core i5-3470, 16GB DDR3 RAM, GTX 1630. All of my SSDs are GPT, including the bootable media used to install Ubuntu. Windows was installed in UEFI mode.
P.S: The partition I had for Ubuntu was 35GB, I think it's ok, right?
EDIT: (extra info) Fast Startup was ALWAYS disabled. Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode, my PC's ''BIOS Mode'' is set to UEFI. In addition, since my question is marked as duplicate, i want to clarify , that in my case, GRUB was ok, and in general, everything was ok. However , things started to get weird at the first time of booting into Windows after installing Ubuntu.
Also, i have tried to see the boot entries using the bcdedit command in cmd, but the only the Windows Boot Manager was there.
EDIT 2, VERY IMPORTANT!
So, i tried entering the UEFI settings as usual. Windows Updates>Recovery>Advanced setup>Advanced options>UEFI settings.
HOWEVER , that was the only time i got the option to boot from another OS (see picture below). That is the only time i see this menu. However, even after i selected Ubuntu it still (for some reason?!) booted into Windows 10.
(the picture is in Greek language but i think it's obvious to understand what it says)
Here the OS selector
Left side, at the bottom it says "Use of other system"
Please someone help! Can't get this figured out....!

Almost certainly ‘fast start-up’ isn’t disabled in Windows -Windows doesn’t shut down completely, when you turn it back on it goes straight back to where you were. There are lots of guides online re how to disable it - please post back if that doesn’t fix it.

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

An  i5-3470 would be UEFI and Windows 10 installed by vendor would be UEFI install as required by Microsoft. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? Windows updates often reset configuration to make Windows first in boot order and may turn fast startup back on. What brand/model system. When you say no Ubuntu entry is that in UEFI system settings or UEFI one time boot menu?

@Will, Fast startup is always disabled. karel, thank you for providing the another question, i tried almost everything from their answers, still nothing. oldfred 13, Ubuntu was installed in UEFI boot mode. The BIOS Mode from msinfo32 from the Run app displays my system ''BIOS mode'' as UEFI. To answer your other question i have an HP PC, from 2012. Also, no Ubuntu entry in UEFI system settings i think, i am not even sure about what UEFI one time boot menu is. To add some more info, I enter UEFI settings from windows updates>recovery>advanced setup. From there, i can enter the UEFI settings.

A small shop building a PC in 2012 just might have done what they were familiar with, and installed Windows 7 in legacy mode (which was subsequently upgraded to 8,10). Just to check, a UEFI Windows must be on a gpt partitioned disk -- if msdos partitioned or if it has an extended partition, Windows is really installed in legacy mode. Might explain some things. HP likes to only boot windows bootloaders, but can be fooled by renames or using the device boot (EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi). Windows loves to reset the boot order, putting win before grub. use efibootmgr -A -bxx to suppress windows.

@ubfan1 , All of my SSDs (including the one windows are installed) are GPT disks. The bootable media to download Ubuntu was also GPT. Thank you for efibootmgr, but I already have tried it, and still got nothing.

OK SO GUYS: After almost 3 days, a lot of hours spent on my computer and after at least 20 possible solutions... I got Ubuntu working!
What i did?
Completely uninstalled ubuntu, then installed it again with a bootable USB.
Then exited and booted to windows.
Ran the CMD as admin, and then executed this command bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi, and for some reason now the GRUB boots normally and lets me select OSs.
Everything works, however, Windows Boot Manager is still first in the Boot Order, and there is no ubuntu.
Tried to power off and power on my PC again and again multiple times to check if the problem was indeed fixed, and everything was ok.
Thank you everyone for providing helpful info and for your interest in my problem.

You may accept your own answer, getting it marked as solved, gaining some reputation points and helping others in the process.
